# In n values, check if exactly one is defined

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an JS-Object (key-value pairs) and the values can be undefined. But i want the code to do something else if **only one** of the values are defined. What is the easiest and best (efficient) way to check that? (See snippet below to clarify)

```js
let obj = {x:undefined, y:undefined, z:1337}
let otherobj = {x:undefined, y:undefined, z:undefined}
let anotherobj = {x:1,y:2,z:3}

if(foo(obj) && !foo(otherobj) && !foo(anotherobj)){
  alert("!!!");
}

function foo(x){
  return true; // ???
}
```

Comment: How about [```Object.keys(OBJ).some```](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)?

Comment: ^ Raqha asked for "only one of the values are defined", my answer is wrong and so is this unfortunately because it's `keys`. Still up for grabs

Comment: Depends what you count as 'defined'. Do `null` or `0` count as 'defined' ?

Comment: @Ergis with defined i mean any non-null or non-undefined values so `0` or `'0'` etc

Comment: @RobertRendell - You can still access the value using `Obj[KEY]` so that does not make my comment irrelevant, I think.

Comment: @RobertRendell I posted a similar answer doing the same mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But i want the code to do something else if only one of the values are defined

You can use `filter` to get only the values that are not 'undefined'.

THen use `.length === 1` to check if it's exactly 1 value

```js
let obj = {x:undefined, y:undefined, z:1337}
let otherobj = {x:undefined, y:undefined, z:undefined}
let anotherobj = {x:1,y:2,z:3}

console.log('Test 1', objHasOneValue(obj));           // true
console.log('Test 2', objHasOneValue(otherobj));      // false
console.log('Test 3', objHasOneValue(anotherobj));    // false

function objHasOneValue(x){
    return Object.values(x).filter(a => a !== undefined).length === 1;
}
```